# get up and running with something

Tags: idioms

The Cambridge Dictionary defines **up and running** in the following way:

*If something, especially a system or a machine, is up and running it is operating*

And gives an example:

*The engineer soon got the air-conditioning up and running again.*

Given this definition and example is the following sentence correct?

**In this lecture we will cover how to get up and running with Julia.**

Should not it be like this?

**In this lecture we will cover how to get Julia up and running.**

I have searched for **getting up and running with sth** but could not find any definition in any dictionary. Is this way of using up and running a slang/everyday English or?

Comment: I think which one you use is largely dependent on who/what "Julia" is.

Comment: It's the name of a software.

Comment: Actually  “*get up and running with” a software* appears to be  a common expression https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get%20up%20and%20running%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2012,cd_max:2013&lr=lang_en

Comment: I have seen tehm already, but I could not find its definition, i.e. why it is lingistically correct. Of course, I understaand its meaning in the context but I am interested in what it means and how a native speaker understands it.

Comment: 'Get up and running with' with the broadened sense 'get to grips with and start to use effectively' **is**   rarer than the prototypical usage, but is used reasonably frequently in reasonable examples on the internet, and is perfectly clear. 'Should it not be' ... entails a judgement call (so no 'answer' here by me), but I'd say the sentence is fine. And your suggested rewrite means something different, ignoring the familiarisation aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me they mean different things.

If I "get Julia up and running" that means I install her on my machine so that she is operating.

But to have "got up and running with Julia" would suggest I had begun using her, and it was not simply Julia, but my own application which was "up and running".

Comment: I read "...get up and runnning with Julia" as meaning that Julia was a woman giving the lecture. However the context probably made it clear that Julia is a development environment or computer language so "getting up and running with Julia" would be similar to "getting up and running" with Ada or Ruby.

Answer (score -1):

I found you a definition in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/up-and-running#:%7E:text=phrase,Synonyms%20of%20up%20and%20running):

> up and running
>
> PHRASE
>
> If something such as a system or place is up and running, it is
> operating normally. We're trying to get the medical facilities up and
> running again.
>
> Synonyms: operating, going, working, functioning

Comment: That's a difition of "up and running" which I mention in my question and the question is about "getting up and running with sth" which apparently as people above say have slightly different meaning.